# Vaadin grid, additional header renders other headers invisible

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

Situation: Assume you have a simple grid, with only 2 columns. First column is frozen. You're trying to join the 2nd column with additional header.

Problem: after joining the column, the column captions (in the header cells) of all columns disappear.

Code to reproduce:

```
Grid table = new Grid();
HeaderRow header = table.addHeaderRowAt(0);

Column c1 = table.addColumn("C1", String.class);
table.setFrozenColumnCount(1);
Column d1 = table.addColumn("D1", Short.class);

c1.setHeaderCaption("Frozen col");
d1.setHeaderCaption("1/10");

header.join("D1");
table.addRow("Example name", (short)25);
```

Without join:

[image: Without join]

With join:

[image: With join]

Am I doing something wrong or this is a Vaadin bug?

Vaadin version: 7.7.0

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join on both columns:

```
header.join("C1", "D1");
```

From `.join(Object... propertyIds)` function:

```
assert propertyIds.length > 1 : "You need to merge at least 2 properties";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Vaadin 8.5.0). You don't need to call `header.join(...)` when there is only one column. Instead, get your header cell by calling `HeaderCell headerCell = headerRow.getCell("D1")`. You can still set the component or text of `headerCell`.